# Group by month and add multiple cols

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i have a table which stores feedbacks and Ratings (between 1 and 5)

I dont even know if this can be done with SQL or not.

Want I what to do is group by month and add up all Q1's, Q2's, Q3's and Q4 in to one column.  The have the amount of records in that grouped month in another column.

Then I could use PHP to work out a average rate in those months.

```
  unixStamp      |  Q1   |   Q2   |   Q3    |   Q4
-----------------------------------------------------
  1362149504     |  5    |    4   |    3    |   5
  1362136774     |  5    |    5   |    2    |   5
  ..........     |  ...  |  ....  |  ....   |  ....
```

This is want I would like the achieve.

```
  Mnth           |  score  |   count  | 
---------------------------------------
  1              |  192    |    20    | 
  2              |  365    |    40    | 
  ..........     |  ...    |  ....    |
```

Comment: I think you should take the unixStamp and fetch the month from that. `score` is something unknown :-D and `count` is Q1+...+Q4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` can contain an arbitrary expression (or the alias from a `SELECT` expression), and you can `SUM()` the 4 quarterly columns together as an aggregate.

```
SELECT
  /* Retrieve only the month from unixStamp */
  MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixStamp)) AS Mnth,
  /* SUM() as an aggregate the 4 quarterly cols */
  SUM(Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4) AS score,
  /* COUNT(*) aggregate will list number of records for group */
  COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Mnth
```

Note that the above will group by the month *only*, not the month/year combination which would seem more appropriate. If you need that, use something like

```
/* Supplies month like 2013-02 */
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtimestamp), '%Y-%m') AS Mnth,
  ...
```

Comment: I know this is off the question can you replace SUM(response_time+friendliness+quality_service+value_money) AS score to something like COUNTIF(response_time+friendliness+quality_service+value_money > 15) AS score -  to give a count of ratings over 15

Comment: @DavidAllen Yes, but it would look like `SUM(CASE WHEN (response_time+friendliness+quality_service+value_money) > 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` It takes the condition and returns 1 or 0 if it is met, then adds the 1/0 to get something the same as count.

Comment: That simply Amazing .  Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` to *unpivot* the data to get the result:

```
SELECT Mnth,
  sum(data) score,
  count(data) `count`
FROM 
(
  SELECT MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixStamp)) Mnth, 
    CASE q.col
      WHEN 'Q1' THEN Q1
      WHEN 'Q2' THEN Q2
      WHEN 'Q3' THEN Q3
      WHEN 'Q4' THEN Q4
    END AS DATA
  FROM yourtable t
  CROSS JOIN 
  (
    SELECT 'Q1' AS col
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Q2'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Q3'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Q4'
  ) q
) s
group by Mnth
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb4c3/1)